# PHP loop creating duplicate database rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm playing about creating a database that contains plaintext and hash values for any combination of passwords, however when they are added to the database I end up with many duplicates before it moves on to the next combination... Any ideas as to why and how to stop it?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$numberof=0;
$alphabet = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");

for($i=0; $i<count($alphabet); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($alphabet); $j++){
        for($k=0; $k<count($alphabet); $k++){
            for($l=0; $l<count($alphabet); $l++){
                $final = $alphabet[$i].$alphabet[$j].$alphabet[$k];
                $hash = md5($final);

                mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO hashes (plain, hash) VALUES ('$final', '$hash')");
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $numberof;
?>
```

Comment: You are not adding the `$alphabet[$l]` to your `$final` string.

Comment: Just as an information : Because md5 generates a string of a fixed length duplicate hashes are possible

Comment: Of course! They're not duplicates, they're just missing the 4th letter! Duuuuh!! :P Thanks, Hidde :)

Comment: To create `$alphabet` array you can use `range`. Like `range('A','Z')`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four nested `for` loops, with counters `$i` `$j` `$k` and `$l`. However, your final string that you use in your query only uses `$i` `$j` and `$k` So you'll have about 26 duplicates. I assume you meant to append the value of `$l` to the end of your string?

Comment: Second problem, after 30 seconds of generation it has an error, I'm guessing because MySQL needs to finish whatever within 30 seconds... any way around that?

Comment: For PHP itself, you can use `ini_set('max_execution_time', ###);`, but there may be other limitations put in place on the server that you're hosting this on.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the last loop. i have update your code as below:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($alphabet); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($alphabet); $j++){
        for($k=0; $k<count($alphabet); $k++){
            $final = $alphabet[$i].$alphabet[$j].$alphabet[$k];
            $hash = md5($final);
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO hashes (plain, hash) VALUES ('$final', '$hash')");           
        }
    }
}
```